# question on pthread_join() and pthread_detach()

Tags: c, pthreads

I wrote this program to practice pthread system calls so I used some printing lines to check the results but they are escaped the output is:

`Thread 1 created
Thread 2 created
test3`

while I think it should be

`thread 1 created
test2
thread 2 created
test3
test1`

The order may change but I should have this lines so why it escape this print statements?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <unistd.h>



void *function();
void *function2();




int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    pthread_t tid;
    int rc;
    rc = pthread_create(&tid, NULL, function(), NULL);
    if(rc > 0){
        fprintf(stderr, "Error\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    pthread_join(tid, NULL);
    sleep(1);
    printf("test1\n");
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}

void *function(){
    int rc;
    pthread_t tid;
    printf("Thread 1 created\n");
    rc = pthread_create(&tid, NULL, function2(), NULL);
    if(rc > 0){
        fprintf(stderr, "Error\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    printf("test2\n");
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}

void *function2(){
    pthread_detach(pthread_self());
    printf("Thread 2 created\n");
    printf("test3\n");
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
rc = pthread_create(&tid, NULL, function(), NULL);
```

You're trying to call `pthread_create()` with the pointer returned by calling `function()` as the function to run in the new thread (Remember, function arguments get evaluated before the function itself is called). Now, `function()` doesn't actually *return* any value, but it calls `function2()` in its body (while evaluating the arguments for another call to `pthread_create()`), which *also* doesn't return any value, but *does* call `pthread_exit()` instead. Since there's only one thread at that point because only the main process thread is running (`pthread_create()` hasn't actually been called yet; the call stack looks like `main() -> function() -> function2()`), the whole program then exits.

You need to call `pthread_create()` with pointers to `function` and `function2`, not the results of calling them:

```
rc = pthread_create(&tid, NULL, function, NULL);
```

etc.